# Uniform convergence of the series of functions $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} {n^n} {\arctan({x}^{n^3})}$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I have pointwise convergence  of the sum of $f_n$ 
in $(-1,1)$.In fact:

1) if $|x|>1$ $f_n(x)$ doesn't converge to zero

2) if $|x|<1$ $f_n(x) \sim n^n x^{n^3}$ for $n\rightarrow +\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\sqrt[n]{n^n x^{n^3}}=0$

Is there uniform convergence in $E=(-1,1)$?

$$\sup\limits_E f_n=\max\left(|f_n(-1)|,|f_n(1)|\right)=n^n \frac{\pi}{4}\rightarrow +\infty$$ 
so there isn't convergence in $E$
if I consider intervals $[a,b]: -1<a<b<1$ there is uniform convergence because

$$\sup\limits_E f_n=\max\left(|f_n(a)|,|f_n(b)|\right)\rightarrow 0$$ for $n\rightarrow +\infty$.

Comment: You can prove normal convergence on the compact subsets of $(-\tan{1},\tan{1})$.

Comment: Why there isn't uniform convergence in all $(-1,1)?$

Comment: There is, since $1< \tan{1}$...

Comment: And what does the given series converge to pointwise?

Comment: I think $f_n(x) := n^n (\mathrm{arctan}(x))^{n^3}$, so 
$$\sup\limits_E f_n=\max\left(|f_n(-1)|,|f_n(1)|\right)=n^n \left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n^3}=\left(n\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)^{n^2}\right)^n\rightarrow 0.$$  Right?

Comment: only x is elevated to $n^3$

Comment: @Giulia   Got it!    Maybe you could put the $n^3$ inside the parentheses.

Comment: Sorry.So it's right my conclusion?